# Bouncy Castle Generating Encryption Keys With Password

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, private-key, public-key

I am in the process of writing an application that accesses very sensitive data (in c#). I have a requirement that says that the application will need to be able to generate public/private keys using a passphrase. This is an absolute must. I will also need to keep the old keys around. We are using bouncy castle lib and PGP. I looked through documentation and cannot seem to find a way to generate them with the phrase.

**Here is how I am generating them currently:**

```
var generator = new DsaKeyPairGenerator();
var paramgen = new DsaParametersGenerator();

paramgen.Init(512, 100, new SecureRandom());

var param = new DsaKeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), paramgen.GenerateParameters());

generator.Init(param);

return generator.GenerateKeyPair();
```

**Here is how I grab they keys:**

```
var publicKey = new PgpPublicKey(Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.PublicKeyAlgorithmTag.Dsa, keys.Public, DateTime.Now);
var privateKey = new PgpPrivateKey(keys.Private, publicKey.KeyId);
```

Is there a way to do this whether it be in bouncy castle or any other encryption lib?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what those Init params mean, but they look insecure to me.  DSA should have 2048 bit modulus (not 512, which can be cracked without too much effort) and at least 160 bit subgroup (this looks like 100 bit).  For your question, check to see if there is a bouncy castle pseudo random number generator that can be seeded by the password, and if so, pass that into Init rather than SecureRandom.  That should work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are right, it is insecure, The above is a sample. :) We plan on using the 2048 bit encryption. I'm checking out your suggestion now.